# php activerecord many to many

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I've three models:

```
// student_id student_name
Student extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $has_many = array(
        array('studentcourses')
    );
}

// course_id course_name
Course extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $has_many = array(
        array('students')
    );
}

// course_id student_id
Studentcourse extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('student')
    );
}
```

So by doing this I'll be able to retrive data from these tables easy:

```
$student = Student::find(1);

foreach ($student->studentcourses as $course)
{
    echo $course->name;
}
```

But insted of typing 'studentcourses', I'd like to type $student->courses instead to get all the courses the student goes to and $course->students to get a list of students in a specific course. How would the relationship setup look to get that?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is many to many relationship. To set it up in PHP-AR:

```
// student_id student_name
Class Student extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $has_many = array(
        array('courses', 'through' => 'studentcourses'),
        array('studentcourses')
    );
}

// course_id course_name
Class Course extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $has_many = array(
        array('students', 'through' => 'studentcourses'),
        array('studentcourses')
    );
}

// course_id student_id
Class Studentcourse extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('student'),
        array('course')
    );
}
```

Don't forget that the *studentcourses* table must contains: **id** (primary key), **student_id**, and **course_id**.